# In Java I created table teller so that we can get table of any number. But the for-loop I created in here is not stopping and is running infinitely

Tags: java, for-loop

I tried to make a program which tells you the table of any number of your choice.
But the loop I created  is not stopping and running infinitely

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number you want to take table of print");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // sc multi starts from 1 and is increase everytime the loop will start so that we can multiply it with number increased//
    
    int scintmulti = 1;
    
    // scnintll is the number which is scint * 10 because we have to take the table until it we reach the scint x 10
    
    int scintll = sc.nextInt()*10;

    for (int scint = sc.nextInt(); scint <= scintll; scintmulti++) {
        System.out.println(scint + "*" + scintmulti + "=" + scint * scintmulti);

        sc.close();
    }

}}
```

Comment: Why should it end? The condition in the for loop is `scint <= scintll` (which means that the for loop will end when `scint > scintll`), but neither value changes during the execution of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the value of `scint` is always the same. That is the reason for infinite loop.

In for loop initialisation happens only once, which means `scint = sc.nextInt();` is called only in the beginning. You might want to increment the value of `scint` instead of `scintmulti` for the loop to end.

EDIT:
I'm guessing this is what you wanted to achieve from the above code snippet. Now the loop terminates once `scintll` is reached.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number you want to take table of print");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // sc multi starts from 1 and is increase everytime the loop will start so that we can multiply it with number increased//

    int scintmulti = 1;

    // scnintll is the number which is scint * 10 because we have to take the table until it we reach the scint x 10

    int scintll = sc.nextInt()*10;

    for (int scint = sc.nextInt(); scint <= scintll; scint++, scintmulti++) {
        System.out.println(scint + "*" + scintmulti + "=" + scint * scintmulti);

        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: But for example, if someone wants the table of 2 then how can we change 2. Thanks for answering btw

Comment: @ShivanshArora Added the code snippet as per my understanding. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple to print the table of a number. The infinite loop is because `scint <= scintll` always stays true. I've reduced some complexity from your code and used more meaningful variable names:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number you want to take table of print");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tableOf = sc.nextInt();
    int start = 1, end = 10;
    
    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " * " + tableOf + " = " + i * tableOf);
    }
    sc.close();
```

If you are using Java 8 or higher, you can also use the stream API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number you want to take table of print");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tableOf = sc.nextInt();
    int start = 1, end = 10;
    
    IntStream
        .rangeClosed(start, end)
        .forEach(elem -> System.out.println(
                elem + " * " + tableOf + " = " + elem * tableOf
            )
         );
    sc.close();
}
```

`IntStream.rangeClosed()` returns a stream of integers from 1 to 10. And `forEach()` takes in a function as parameter to apply on each integer. Each integer is passed to the function as `elem` and then the `System.out.println()` is executed for each number.
`elem -> System.out.println(elem + " * " + tableOf + " = " + elem * tableOf)` is called a lambda function. `elem` is a parameter and the part after `->` is the body of the function.
Make sure to include `java.util.stream.*`.